# Linux service to gather input from user on login

Tags: linux, services

I would like to define a systemd service that, depending on certain conditions, presents the user with a prompt to type in some text before that user's login shell prompt is made available.

Here is an example of the type of thing I want: When a user logs in before anything else and before the user can type in anything a script is run prompting the user to type in their preferred first name. This name is saved in a file in their home directory. However, if the first name file already exists the script does nothing.

This is how it would look to the user logging in:

```
my-server login: joe-user
password: <user types in password>
System notice: joe-user we need to gather some information.
----
Please type in your preferred first name:
```

The script that does the prompting and file writing is easy enough, but how do I write the service so that the user gets the script immediately upon login? This should work no matter which shell the user happens to be using.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a right job for a systemd service. I would rather used .profile files.

Answer (score 0):

Although not a 100% match - it seems close enough - there is a tool called `systemd-ask-password` - this is meant as a way to provide a password to a systemd service which you do not want to store on disk.

There exists several agents which can answer such a query, for example `systemd-tty-ask-password-agent`.

But be warned: Answering such a query requires a privileged user (because it is a system-wide query, and not bound to any user).

If you want to ask something a specific user who has no privileges, a self-written script which is executed on login (called for example from  `$HOME/.profile`) might be a better place for such a query...